# how can i add chose button to upload .sql file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

how can i add chose button to select .sql file and upload data to mysql

this is chose button code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php">
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is upload .sql file code is working perfect but i want to add chose button to upload .sql file to mysql how can i add chose button please help me

```
<?php

// Name of the file
$filename = 'churc.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'root';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = '';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'dump';

// Connect to MySQL server
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
// Select database
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";
?>
```

Comment: You plan to aggressively secure this, I hope. Your current PHP file would accept a SQL upload from anyone anywhere.

Comment: What is it you need help with? You have a form, though it is missing `enctype='multipart/form-data'` necessary for uploading files.  Do you know how to read from the `$_FILES` superglobal?

Comment: how can i do this please help me

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a choose button"?

Comment: i want to upload .sql file so this code is upload directly i want to add chose button to select .sql and upload it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exec()` and the command

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < your-dump-file.sql
```

To import a mysql dump file. It's a lot easier and more bullet proofed than to write an own mysql dump file parser.

**Or** to access your `img` form field in your PHP script use the `$_FILES['img']` variable. It contains all the information about the uploaded file. And add to your `form` tag the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that your file gets uploaded to the server.

Comment: This is not at all what was asked.